# If$ a$, $b$, and $c$ are elements of a ring, does the equation always have a solution $x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $a, b,$ and $c$ are elements of a ring, does the equation ax+b=c always have a solution $x$? If it does, must the solution be unique? Answer the same question given that a is a unit.

I am not sure if my thinking is correct, but I think that there will always be a solution $x$ if $a, b$, and $c$ are elements of a ring. Yet, I do not think the solution is unique.

I am not sure how to prove my answer, if I am correct.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: When you say "does the equation always have a solution," to what equation are you referring?

Comment: What equation are you talking about?

Comment: Is the equation $ax+b=c$? If so, isn't this the same as $ax=(c-b)$? And what can you say when $a$ is invertible? And can you think to examples in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for the case when $a$ is not invertible?

Comment: I am very sorry. As I was typing the question I forgot to put the equation. I edited it so it is now there. Thank you for this solution, I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $ax+b=c$ not necessarily solvable in general in a ring $R$ . Indeed  if your ring is $\mathbb Z$ the equation $2x+3=8$ not admitted solution in $\mathbb Z.$

In the case where $a\in R^*$ the group of units of $R$ the equation in question admits a solution  namely $x=(c-b)a^{-1}$ and is unique.